# How to disable the previous dates in the java script calender..?

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript calender in my project. It is working perfectly. But i want to disable the previous dates in the calender. Code used for  that calender is as below..

```
    /* Code starts here*/

    var datepickr = (function() {
            var datepickrs = [],
            currentDate = new Date(),
            date = {
                current: {
                    year: function() {
                        return currentDate.getFullYear();
                    },
                    month: {
                        integer: function() {
                            return currentDate.getMonth();
                        },
                        string: function(full) {
                            var date = currentDate.getMonth();
                            return monthToStr(date, full);
                        }
                    },
                    day: function() {
                        return currentDate.getDate();           
                    }
                },
                month: {
                    string: function(full, currentMonthView) {
                        var date = currentMonthView;
                        return monthToStr(date, full);
                    },
                    numDays: function(currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
                        // checks to see if february is a leap year otherwise return the respective # of days
                        return (currentMonthView == 1 && !(currentYearView & 3) && (currentYearView % 1e2 || !(currentYearView % 4e2))) ? 29 : daysInMonth[currentMonthView];
                    }
                }
            },
            weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wednes', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Satur'],
            months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
            suffix = { 1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd', 21: 'st', 22: 'nd', 23: 'rd', 31: 'st' },
            buildCache = [],
            handlers = {
                calendarClick: function(e) {
                    if(e.target.className) {
                        switch(e.target.className) {
                            case 'prev-month':
                            case 'prevMonth':
                                this.currentMonthView--;
                                if(this.currentMonthView < 0) {
                                    this.currentYearView--;
                                    this.currentMonthView = 11;
                                }
                                rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                            break;
                            case 'next-month':
                            case 'nextMonth':
                                this.currentMonthView++;
                                if(this.currentMonthView > 11) {
                                    this.currentYearView++;
                                    this.currentMonthView = 0;
                                }
                                rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                            break;
                            case 'day':
                                this.element.value = formatDate(new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, e.target.innerHTML).getTime(), this.config.dateFormat);
                                this.close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                documentClick: function(e) {
                    if(e.target != this.element && e.target != this.calendar) {
                        var parentNode = e.target.parentNode;
                        if(parentNode != this.calender) {
                            while(parentNode != this.calendar) {
                                parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                                if(parentNode == null) {
                                    this.close();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            function formatDate(milliseconds, dateFormat) {
                var formattedDate = '',
                dateObj = new Date(milliseconds),
                format = {
                    d: function() {
                        var day = format.j();
                        return (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
                    },
                    D: function() {
                        return weekdays[format.w()].substring(0, 3);
                    },
                    j: function() {
                        return dateObj.getDate();
                    },
                    l: function() {
                        return weekdays[format.w()] + 'day';
                    },
                    S: function() {
                        return suffix[format.j()] || 'th';
                    },
                    w: function() {
                        return dateObj.getDay();
                    },
                    F: function() {
                        return monthToStr(format.n(), true);
                    },
                    m: function() {
                        var month = format.n() + 1;
                        return (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
                    },
                    M: function() {
                        return monthToStr(format.n(), false);
                    },
                    n: function() {
                        return dateObj.getMonth();
                    },
                    Y: function() {
                        return dateObj.getFullYear();
                    },
                    y: function() {
                        return format.Y().toString().substring(2, 4);
                    }
                },
                formatPieces = dateFormat.split('');

                foreach(formatPieces, function(formatPiece) {
                    formattedDate += format[formatPiece] ? format[formatPiece]() : formatPiece;
                });

                return formattedDate;
            }

            function foreach(items, callback) {
                var i = 0, x = items.length;
                for(i; i < x; i++) {
                    if(callback(items[i], i) === false) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            function addEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
                if(element.addEventListener) {
                    element.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
                } else if(element.attachEvent) {
                    var fixedCallback = function(e) {
                        e = e || window.event;
                        e.preventDefault = (function(e) {
                            return function() { e.returnValue = false; }
                        })(e);
                        e.stopPropagation = (function(e) {
                            return function() { e.cancelBubble = true; }
                        })(e);
                        e.target = e.srcElement;
                        callback.call(element, e);
                    };
                    element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, fixedCallback);
                }
            }

            function removeEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
                if(element.removeEventListener) {
                    element.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
                } else if(element.detachEvent) {
                    element.detachEvent('on' + eventType, callback);
                }
            }

            function buildNode(nodeName, attributes, content) {
                var element;

                if(!(nodeName in buildCache)) {
                    buildCache[nodeName] = document.createElement(nodeName);
                }

                element = buildCache[nodeName].cloneNode(false);

                if(attributes != null) {
                    for(var attribute in attributes) {
                        element[attribute] = attributes[attribute];
                    }
                }

                if(content != null) {
                    if(typeof(content) == 'object') {
                        element.appendChild(content);
                    } else {
                        element.innerHTML = content;
                    }
                }

                return element;
            }

            function monthToStr(date, full) {
                return ((full == true) ? months[date] : ((months[date].length > 3) ? months[date].substring(0, 3) : months[date]));
            }

            function isToday(day, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
                return day == date.current.day() && currentMonthView == date.current.month.integer() && currentYearView == date.current.year();
            }

            function buildWeekdays() {
                var weekdayHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
                foreach(weekdays, function(weekday) {
                    weekdayHtml.appendChild(buildNode('th', {}, weekday.substring(0, 2)));
                });
                return weekdayHtml;
            }

            function rebuildCalendar() {
                while(this.calendarBody.hasChildNodes()){
                    this.calendarBody.removeChild(this.calendarBody.lastChild);
                }

                var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
                numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);

                this.currentMonth.innerHTML = date.month.string(this.config.fullCurrentMonth, this.currentMonthView) + ' ' + this.currentYearView;
                this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
            }

            function buildCurrentMonth(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
                return buildNode('span', { className: 'current-month' }, date.month.string(config.fullCurrentMonth, currentMonthView) + ' ' + currentYearView);
            }

            function buildMonths(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
                var months = buildNode('div', { className: 'months' }),
                prevMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'prev-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'prevMonth' }, '&lt;')),
                nextMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'next-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'nextMonth' }, '&gt;'));

                months.appendChild(prevMonth);
                months.appendChild(nextMonth);

                return months;
            }

            function buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
                var calendarBody = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                row = buildNode('tr'),
                dayCount = 0, i;

                // print out previous month's "days"
                for(i = 1; i <= firstOfMonth; i++) {
                    row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
                    dayCount++;
                }

                for(i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
                    // if we have reached the end of a week, wrap to the next line
                    if(dayCount == 7) {
                        calendarBody.appendChild(row);
                        row = buildNode('tr');
                        dayCount = 0;
                    }

                    var todayClassName = isToday(i, currentMonthView, currentYearView) ? { className: 'today' } : null;
                    row.appendChild(buildNode('td', todayClassName, buildNode('span', { className: 'day' }, i)));

                    dayCount++;
                }

                // if we haven't finished at the end of the week, start writing out the "days" for the next month
                for(i = 1; i <= (7 - dayCount); i++) {
                    row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
                }

                calendarBody.appendChild(row);

                return calendarBody;
            }

            function buildCalendar() {
                var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
                numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView),
                self = this;

                var inputLeft = inputTop = 0,
                obj = this.element;

                if(obj.offsetParent) {
                    do {
                        inputLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
                        inputTop += obj.offsetTop;
                    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                }

                var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
                calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';

                this.currentMonth = buildCurrentMonth(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView)
                var months = buildMonths(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);
                months.appendChild(this.currentMonth);

                var calendar = buildNode('table', null, buildNode('thead', null, buildNode('tr', { className: 'weekdays' }, buildWeekdays())));
                this.calendarBody = buildNode('tbody');
                this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
                calendar.appendChild(this.calendarBody);

                calendarContainer.appendChild(months);
                calendarContainer.appendChild(calendar);

                document.body.appendChild(calendarContainer);

                addEvent(calendarContainer, 'click', function(e) { handlers.calendarClick.call(self, e); });

                return calendarContainer;
            }

            return function(elementId, userConfig) {
                var self = this;

                this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
                this.config = {
                    fullCurrentMonth: true,
                    dateFormat: 'F jS, Y'
                };
                this.currentYearView = date.current.year();
                this.currentMonthView = date.current.month.integer();

                if(userConfig) {
                    for(var key in userConfig) {
                        if(this.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            this.config[key] = userConfig[key];
                        }
                    }
                }

                this.documentClick = function(e) { handlers.documentClick.call(self, e); }

                this.open = function(e) {
                    addEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);

                    foreach(datepickrs, function(datepickr) {
                        if(datepickr != self) {
                            datepickr.close();
                        }
                    });

                    self.calendar.style.display = 'block';
                }

                this.close = function() {
                    removeEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);
                    self.calendar.style.display = 'none';
                }

                this.calendar = buildCalendar.call(this);

                datepickrs.push(this);

                if(this.element.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
                    addEvent(this.element, 'focus', this.open);
                } else {
                    addEvent(this.element, 'click', this.open);
                }
            }
        })();
/* Code Ends here*/
```

In the above code do i want to add something more or want to change something..?

Please let me know..

Thanks in advance,
Sree ram.

Comment: You are asking yourself if you want to add or change something? Try something first please.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should prevent any dates prior to the current date from being selectable.

```
$('#element').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

Hopefully this answers your question.